# Cocos2d: pixel perfect collision for batched sprites

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, collision-detection, pixel

I found a pixel perfect collision algorithm developed by Daniel Vilchez and included in a project shared [in this cocos2d-iphone.org forum topic](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/18522).

Below there is the part of the algorithm I am interested. I am trying to modify this because whenever I used CCRenderTexture, as originally in the code, the App crashed.

I am thinking of [alternative methods based on circle collision](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5735575/how-to-do-pixel-perfect-collision-on-many-sprites-in-cocos2d) but those are "not pixel perfect" and in the case my bullet is a wave with [this shape](http://www.semionaut.net/wp-content/uploads/SoundWave1.png) it wouldn't work well.

**I am wondering how can I get the algorithm working with sprites batched in a CCSpriteBatchNode? And if so does this strictly include the usage of CCRenderTexture? **

To be precise, this question is partially related to [this other question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12991649/cocos2d-creating-an-instance-of-ccrendertexture-crashes-my-app-but-cant-figure), on creating an instance of CCRenderTexture that causes my App to crash. I post two different ones because here I am asking about the algorithm, in the other one I just ask why CCRenderTexture causes my App to crash (without using Daniel's pixel perfect algorithm, but just creating an instance of CCRenderTexture).

Adapted CODE (here is missing CCRenderTexture because it made my app crashing, so I commented out the usage of _rt - instance of CCRenderTexture). The code does not work properly, so I guess I need CCRenderTexture and hence I asked the question:

```
-(BOOL) isPixelPerfectCollisionBetweenSpriteA:(CCSprite*)spr1 spriteB:(CCSprite*) spr2
{
    BOOL isCollision = NO; 
    CGRect intersection = CGRectIntersection([spr1 boundingBox], [spr2 boundingBox]);

    // Look for simple bounding box collision
    if (!CGRectIsEmpty(intersection))
    {
        // Get intersection info
        unsigned int x = intersection.origin.x;
        unsigned int y = intersection.origin.y;
        unsigned int w = intersection.size.width;
        unsigned int h = intersection.size.height;
        unsigned int numPixels = w * h;

        //NSLog(@"\nintersection = (%u,%u,%u,%u), area = %u",x,y,w,h,numPixels);

        // Draw into the RenderTexture
        //[_rt beginWithClear:0 g:0 b:0 a:0];

        // Render both sprites: first one in RED and second one in GREEN
        glColorMask(1, 0, 0, 1);
        [spr1 visit];
        glColorMask(0, 1, 0, 1);
        [spr2 visit];
        glColorMask(1, 1, 1, 1); 

        // Get color values of intersection area
        ccColor4B *buffer = malloc( sizeof(ccColor4B) * numPixels );
        glReadPixels(x, y, w, h, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

        //[_rt end];

        // Read buffer
        unsigned int step = 1;
        for(unsigned int i=0; i<numPixels; i+=step)
        {
            ccColor4B color = buffer[i];

            if (color.r > 0 && color.g > 0)
            {
                isCollision = YES;
                break;
            }
        }

        // Free buffer memory
        free(buffer);
    }

    return isCollision;
```

EDIT: I found also [KKPixelMaskSprite](http://www.learn-cocos2d.com/2011/12/fast-pixelperfect-collision-detection-cocos2d-code-1of2/) but it doesn't seem to work for high resolution sprites batched in CCSpriteBatchNodes (see [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15697152/kobold2d-pixel-perfect-collision-detection-device-issue) here).

Comment: You didn't read the entire forum thread. There is a solution for sprite batch node.

Comment: @John thanks. I saw the solution but it seems to me that they say that it does not work for rotated sprites. Are you aware that they found a solution for handling rotation and spritebatchnodes?

Comment: Did you try it ? I used it in one of my projects and had no trouble with rotating sprites.

Comment: Ok, will try it. I was put off by the commments and thought would have been a waste of time trying it, but will do. Did you notice any performance decrease in terms of fps?

Comment: That all depends on exactly what you're doing - I had 60fps on a 1st generation iPhone. You might have terrible performance. It depends on what you're trying to do. You should just try it and see how it works.